# Azure DevOps: I'm caching nuget packages, but the Build task fails to use the cached packages

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I'm using the Cache@2 DevOps task to cache nuget packages from multiple projects:

```
variables:
  NUGET_PACKAGES: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nuget/packages

  - task: Cache@2
    displayName: 'NuGet cache'
    inputs:
      key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**,!**/obj/**'
      restoreKeys: |
        nuget | "$(Agent.OS)"
        nuget
      path: $(NUGET_PACKAGES)
      cacheHitVar: 'CACHE_RESTORED'

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'NuGet restore'
    condition: ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, true)
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build solution'
    ...
```

I'm following the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/caching-nuget?view=azure-devops

In the 'NuGet cache' step, if there is a cache, it is restored:

```
Resolved to: nuget|"Windows_NT"|Gor2Y1OZWvAeaan3RC3GH9D0ldp6z17wm6JB2YUxrS0=
There is a cache hit: `nuget|"Windows_NT"|Gor2Y1OZWvAeaan3RC3GH9D0ldp6z17wm6JB2YUxrS0=`
Path = 
Type = tar
Code Page = UTF-8
Characteristics = ASCII

Everything is Ok

Folders: 6022
Files: 8938
Size:       1894324465
Compressed: 7660544
Process exit code: 0
Cache restored.
```

If there is a cache hit, the 'NuGet restore' task is skipped:

```
Evaluating: ne(variables['CACHE_RESTORED'], True)
Expanded: ne('true', True)
Result: False
```

**Then comes my problem. The 'Build solution' task fails with thousands of errors like these**

> ##[error]NHO.Core\IdentityServerClientStartup.cs(32,12): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OwinStartupAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It cannot resolve references to classes in NuGet packages.

Any idea why this fails? I'm following the documentation exactly, but I don't know if I'm still missing something?

**Update: Possible solution/source of error**

It seems to be an error in the documentation.

If I run the NuGet restore step normally, without the condition

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

it is *a lot quicker* than normal (20 seconds instead of 2 minutes), so I'm guessing it uses the cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation provides only a basic case that all packages and references are stored in `.nuget/packages` and no assets files are required. In this case, the users can skip the restore task and just perform the cache task.

However, in many other cases, performing a restore task is necessary if using Microsoft-hosted agent. Since most packages are already cached by cache task, the running time of nuget restore task will be significantly reduced.